# How to implement dynamic pagination in jsp, after search result with some criteria?

Tags: jsp, servlets

In **JSP** i have **quick search box** where some criteria fields are there, i searched for records and it is something 100's of records after search. i want to implement **pagination** on searched result for 10 record per page.

I am using jsp and servlet for application.

thanks

Comment: What's your concrete question? What have you tried?

Comment: There are a heap of tutorials available on the internet. Google it mate.

Comment: I have tried like this <prev> 1 2 3 4 5 <next>  and given link on every page number as <a href="/myApp/myServlet?offSet=0&limit=10">3</a>      <a href="/myApp/myServlet?offSet=10&limit=20">3</a> and so on... but it is fetching records without considering search criteria...

Comment: @AnkitKumar Have you passed the limit to your database query?

Comment: no, i am searching from 1000,s of records and just setting limit as 10.

Comment: @AnkitKumar You need to set the limit in your database query as well in order to do custom pagination otherwise it will fetch all the records from table or view.

Answer (score 0):

To do this make form (method="GET" action="pagination-url") with your search criteria and "page" param. After that write jquery function that disables pagination links and populate form with number of page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".pagination a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkHref = $(this).prop("href");
        var page = getURLParameter("page", linkHref); // get number of next page
        $("#showParamsForm").find("#pageInput").val(page);
        cleanShowParamsForm();
        $("#showParamsForm").submit();
    });
});

function cleanShowParamsForm() {
    $("#showParamsForm input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

After clicking a pagination link GET-request with your criteria params and page number will be submitted